# Admob ads are not showing in Unity, C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

My Admob ads are not showing in my app on Android, I tried everything, different versions of unity, types of ads, re-installation of admob plugin, different combinations of player settings for android compilation.

Log on Unity (I tested it on Android) is:

Dummy IsLoaded
Dummy ShowIntertitial

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class ControllerMain : MonoBehaviour
{

public Button LV1, LV2, LV3, LV4, LV5, LV6, LV7, LV8, LV9, LV10;
public int ReturnedVal;
private string MyIdA = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173318";
//private InterstitialAd fullscreenad;
//private string FullScreenID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173651";
//private BannerView bannerView;
private InterstitialAd InterFULLSC;
void LOV1() {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}
void LOV2()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
}
void LOV3()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(3);
}
void LOV4()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
}
void LOV5()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(5);
}
void LOV6()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(6);
}
void LOV7()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(7);
}
void LOV8()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(8);
}
void LOV9()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(9);
}
void LOV10()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(10);
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
    this.InterFULLSC = new InterstitialAd(MyIdA);
    //LV1.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    ReturnedVal = GameMonitor.IsPassed;
    if (ReturnedVal > 0)
    {
        AdRequest requ = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        this.InterFULLSC.LoadAd(requ);

        if (this.InterFULLSC.IsLoaded()) {
            this.InterFULLSC.Show();
        }
        //MobileAds.Initialize(appID);
        //go
        //bannerView = new BannerView("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        //AdRequest requ = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        //bannerView.LoadAd(requ);
        //bannerView.Show();
        //end
        //fullscreenad = new InterstitialAd(FullScreenID);
        //AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        //fullscreenad.LoadAd(request);
        //if (fullscreenad.IsLoaded())
        //{
        //    fullscreenad.Show();
        //}
        //else { Debug.Log("Didn't load"); }

    }
    Debug.Log(ReturnedVal);
    LV1.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
    LV2.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV3.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV4.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV5.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV6.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV7.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV8.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV9.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV10.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.black;
    LV2.interactable = false;
    LV3.interactable = false;
    LV4.interactable = false;
    LV5.interactable = false;
    LV6.interactable = false;
    LV7.interactable = false;
    LV8.interactable = false;
    LV9.interactable = false;
    LV10.interactable = false;
    LV1.interactable = true;
    LV1.onClick.AddListener(LOV1);
    if (ReturnedVal == 2 || ReturnedVal>2) {
        LV2.interactable = true;
        LV2.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV2.onClick.AddListener(LOV2);
    }
    if (ReturnedVal == 3 || ReturnedVal > 3)
    {
        LV3.interactable = true;
        LV3.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV3.onClick.AddListener(LOV3);
    }
    if (ReturnedVal == 4 || ReturnedVal > 4)
    {
        LV4.interactable = true;
        LV4.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV4.onClick.AddListener(LOV4);
    }
    if (ReturnedVal == 5 || ReturnedVal > 5)
    {
        LV5.interactable = true;
        LV5.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV5.onClick.AddListener(LOV5);
    }
    if (ReturnedVal == 6 || ReturnedVal > 6)
    {
        LV6.interactable = true;
        LV6.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV6.onClick.AddListener(LOV6);
    }
    if (ReturnedVal == 7 || ReturnedVal > 7)
    {
        LV7.interactable = true;
        LV7.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV7.onClick.AddListener(LOV7);
    }
    if (ReturnedVal == 8 || ReturnedVal > 8)
    {
        LV8.interactable = true;
        LV8.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV8.onClick.AddListener(LOV8);
    }
    if (ReturnedVal == 9 || ReturnedVal > 9)
    {
        LV9.interactable = true;
        LV9.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV9.onClick.AddListener(LOV9);
    }
    if (ReturnedVal == 10)
    {
        LV10.interactable = true;
        LV10.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        LV10.onClick.AddListener(LOV10);
    }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the ads using the following format:

```
MobileAds.Initialize(appID);
```

Also you are trying to load and show the ad together in start function which might be one of the reason for the issue you are facing.
Load the ad in start function but show the ad on any button click by calling the below function

```
  void ShowAd(){
    if (this.InterFULLSC.IsLoaded()) {
                this.InterFULLSC.Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback,  but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Use test app id and test interstitial ad id's and check once. Don't use live ad id